# PostCSS CSSNext @media and color() not working with webpack 2

Tags: webpack-2, css-loader, cssnext

I'm upgrading a project from webpack 1 to 2, and am seeing some strange behavior with `postcss-cssnext` where some css next features, most notably `color()` functions and all my `@media` queries just aren't working anymore.

My webpack config with webpack 2 looks like this. What am I doing wrong here?

```
{ 
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    { 
      loader: 'style-loader' 
    },
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        localIndentName: 'localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        sourceMap: true,
        modules: true,
        importLoaders: 1
      }
    },
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        plugins: [
          postcssImport({ path: './app/css/common' }),
          postcssCssnext({ browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions'] }),
          postcssReporter({ clearMessages: true })
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

postcss-loader is probably responsible for this change (1.3.x).
According to doc, you should use a function for "plugins" option.
Or use an array but in a postcss.config.js file.

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        use: [
          …
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: function () {
                return [
                  postcssImport({ path: './app/css/common' }),
                  postcssCssnext({ browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions'] }),
                  postcssReporter({ clearMessages: true })
                ];
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Or via postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    postcssImport({ path: './app/css/common' }),
    postcssCssnext({ browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions'] }),
    postcssReporter({ clearMessages: true })
  ]
}
```

(and in webpack)

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        use: [
          …
          'postcss-loader',
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```